# connect next.Js with django

Tags: django, next.js

I'm trying to get Next to work with my django template.
My `urls.py` looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path('^(?!static).*$', index),
]
```

I'm basically redirecting every `/foo/bar` request to the index view, which renders the `index.html` template, which looks like this:

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="{% static "dist/bundles/pages/_document.js" %}"></script>
</head>
<body>
  Hey
</body>
</html>
```

So my question is, which one is the "main" next JS file, that should go inside my `<script type="application/javascript" src="..."></script>`?

Comment: Curious what you settled on for this?